# Huge allocations bytes

Tags: ios, instruments, allocation

I'm nearly finished with writing my first iOS application, but I ran into a problem now, at some points the app is freezing up for a few seconds, and I can't find out why.

So to give you an idea of the app, the layout sort of looks the same like the facebook one, so I have a menu on the left and content on the right

```
 ------------------------------------
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|    UI     |                       |
|   TABLE   |     UITABLEVIEW       |
|   VIEW    |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
|           |                       |
 ------------------------------------
```

On the left there's a list of users, clicking on it will show a modal view with the profile.

To give you an idea on the amount of allocations, this is when I first launch my app:
[image]

It actually seems a lot already, the tableview on the right consists of cells with an image and 4 labels (and sometimes a UITextView)

When I click on a user and launch the modal view, the allocations go up with about 20MB
[image]

But then, and I think this is the problem, when I close the modal view and open it up again, the allocations go up with 50MB

[image]

That doesn't seem very normal and I find it hard to check where exactly it goes wrong.

So a view questions:
 - When closing a modal view shouldn't the allocations go down again?
 - How can I see where it goes wrong, seems like there is a huge memory leak somewhere

Comment: Open the view again and see if usage jumps up further. If so, it's a leak. If not, it's just lazy memory reclamation. (Why free resources when the free space isn't needed and you'll just have to re-allocate them later?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it only keeps going op, every time i open it it goes up with another 30MB or so

Comment: Also when I dismiss the modal view, my active bytes don't go down

Comment: Okay, so now you have a leak. The leak is whichever allocations keep going up each time you open/close a view.

Comment: From what I can see, it seems that the cell used in my tableview are causing this problem. They are both used in the start screen and the view that is opened as a modal Maybe they're just quite heavy (3 buttons, 2 views, 8 labels)

Comment: After taking a closer look at the custom cell I managed to make it perform much better, although when opening the view it stil lags, could this be because that the data is instantly loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much looking around I had a few problems

1. I didn't release anything in my custom cells (Just stupid of me)
2. When opening the modal view data was already pushed in the table, this caused everything to freeze up for a sec